# Converting c# decryption method to android

Tags: c#, android, encryption, aes

I am trying to decrypt in JAVA a string that was encrypted in C#.
In c# the decryption is succesffull with this method:

```
  AesCryptoServiceProvider aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        aesProvider.BlockSize = 128;
        aesProvider.KeySize = 128;
        aesProvider.Key = strKey;
        aesProvider.IV = strIV;
        aesProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aesProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = aesProvider.CreateDecryptor(aesProvider.Key, aesProvider.IV);
        byte[] DecryptedBytes = cryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(EncryptedBytes, 0, EncryptedBytes.Length);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DecryptedBytes);
```

What I am trying to do is convert this method to JAVA (Android), this is what I have tried, but get an error message ("Pad block corrupted"):

```
 try
       {
           byte[] IV = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
           byte[] KEY = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

           SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
           Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance ("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

           cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(IV));

           byte[] bytesData = Utilities.Base64Coder.decode(data);

           Log.i("bytesData", String.valueOf(bytesData.length));

           String strResult = new String(cipher.doFinal(bytesData));


            Log.i("decrypted string", strResult);
            return strResult;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            Log.i("decrypted FAILED", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
```

10X :)

Comment: try looking at [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Pad+block+corrupted)

Comment: I did look, but didn`t find the answer there..actually most of the realted questions were never solved.

Comment: I'd start by writing encrypter code for each, compare the encrypted versions of known inputs, and adjust the settings in each until they match.   Looking at your exception what other options have you tried for `aesProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7` in C#?

Comment: Double check the key and IV again, and make sure the Base64Decoder is working as expected. Your algorithms look compatible to me. By the way, after you successfully get the data decrypted you'll want use something like `new String(cipher.doFinal(bytesData), "UTF-8");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whom ever search and get to this question - this code works fine, the problem was with the key that was different between c# and Java.

GregS - 10X for raising my attention to check it again.